# android intentService concurrency

Tags: android, android-intentservice

What happens in android when i have an intentService that gets called multiple times before onHandleIntent completes. Let me show you an example:

say i have a intent service that looks like this:

```
public class AService extends IntentService {
    public AService() {
        super("AService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            // magic happens here but lets pretend it takes 3 mins.
        }

}
```

Now lets say i call this service multiple times, do the requests get queued ? How is concurrency handled or am i expected to handle it by putting a synch block in onHandleIntent like this:

```
synchronized (AService.class) {
            //do stuff here 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now lets say i call this service multiple times, do the requests get queued ?

Yes, assuming that by "call this service", you mean call `startService()` with an `Intent` that resolves to this service. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.